# Links no more clickable after moving <?include .. .php")?> above main <div> in PHP file

Tags: php, html, php-include

Would anyone have some clue on this issue I cannot manage to find a fix for:
On homepage www.vertu-approved.fr none of the links in the left menu are working after I made the following small change in the website home.php file:

BEFORE:

```
<body>
<div id="main_container">
<? include ("media/includes/header.php")?>
<?include ("media/includes/leftmenu2.php")?>
```

AFTER:

```
 <body>
 <?include ("media/includes/leftmenu2.php")?>   
 <div id="main_container">
 <? include ("media/includes/header.php")?>
```

Since I moved `<?include ("media/includes/leftmenu2.php")?>` above the `<div id="main_container">` all links in the leftmenu2 have stopped working.

The issue is happening in Safari, Firefox and Chrome.

- So far I have verified in both home.php and leftmenu2.php that all `<div>` have an associated closing `</div>` tag positioned at the right place. 
  Ps. Quite surprisingly if I intentionally remove the final closing `</div>` in leftmenu2.php it makes the links clickable again (but messes out the whole page page structure & formatting).
- I have read that the issue may be caused because home.php is at the website root directory while leftmenu2.php is located in a sub folder. However leftmenu2.php path i.e. media/includes/leftmenu2.php appears fine to me, and with this same path things were working fine before I made that initial small change.

How can I get the links to be clickable again while keeping leftmenu2.php outside the `<div id="main_container">`?

Many thanks

Comment: This problem may due to the change in the location of the php files in the server directory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rule to `#middleleft_pan` in your stylesheet (style.css line number 135),

```
#middleleft_pan{
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Explanation: I see a `<div>` with ID **main_container** which is stacking above your menu. So your menu does not get the mouse over.

Comment: Many thanks! It fixed the problem :-).

May I ask ask where you see that `<div>` with ID main_container stacking above the menu? Are you referring to the styles.css file?

Comment: When you use Google Chrome, on inspecting your div, you can see that.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am unsure if I am looking at the right place: I removed your fix (for test purposes) and if I inspect the div with Google Chrome I see:   
>`<div id="middleleft_pan">_</div>`  
>`<div id="main_container">_</div>`  

So it appears to me this main_container is correctly positioned below the middleleft_pan (which contains the left_menu div). I cannot see where it is stacking above the menu?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Header must be placed top of all, or deplace the HTML code that you need from header to leftmenu2.php

Because there a PHP codes that you placed on header and leftmenu2.php need them.

Comment: Thank you, in fact that required html code is in home.php file already.

Answer (score 0):

your #main_container is appearing over the top of the menu

add:

```
z-index: -1;
```

to #main_container  in your css file.

Comment: Thank you. I tried adding `z-index: -1;` to #main_container in the css file -> it could fix the issue with leftmenu2, but then all links in main container now could not be clickable anymore.